# Datagrid remove row

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid

Is it possible to after you deleted a row from the datagrid, that it links to a command or event so I can throw it out of the SQL too?

Right now i have this grid. I can edit it trough i:Interaction.Triggers.

Is there something similar for Delete?

```
XAML:
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Contactpersons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" Margin="35,99,8,10" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Naam"  Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bedrijf" Binding="{Binding Company}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Functie"  Binding="{Binding JobRole/Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stad" Binding="{Binding City}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="E-mail" Binding="{Binding Email}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Telefoon" Binding="{Binding Phone}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="GSM" Binding="{Binding Cellphone}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

C#:

    public ICommand EditCommand
            {
                get { return new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(Edit); }
            }

            private void Edit(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    Contactperson b = e.RemovedItems[0] as Contactperson;
                    Contactperson.EditPerson(b);
                }
            }
```

So is there an equivalent like this for delete instead of edit?

Comment: U can add a button with event in that u can write code for delete in Database right if i understood correctly ?

Comment: Or u need after row deletion from datagrid it should do the job ?

Comment: I will have a textbox with "Typ the person's name here" The person's name who's in there will be deleted from the sql. I use the MVVM model.

Answer (score 0):

In datagrid u have an event called UnloadingRow

```
 private void dgv_UnloadingRow(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {

          // Add your deletion code from SQL.

    }
```

**UPDATE :-**

Please check this link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42548/MVVM-and-the-WPF-DataGrid)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I use the mvvm model. So i rather not work in the code behind.

Comment: I am not good in MVVM. Still i guess u can create a event in your viewModel and can embed in DataGrid events ??